# Add dict into Item dynamodb python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I have an item register on dynamodb with the next structure:

```
{
"OwnerID":"12312wqeq", 
"license":"23423werwegdf",
"MaintenanceList":{
        "10-11-2018":{
                      "garage" : "lopcars",
                      "city" : "NY",
                      "country" "USA",
                      "location" : "1929-1927 Fulton St Brooklyn"
              }
       }
}
```

I need to add a new Maintenance to the list, and I tried this:

```
response=table.update_item(
    Key={
        "OwnerID":"12312wqeq", 
        "license":"23423werwegdf",'
    }
    ,UpdateExpression = "SET #d1=:dt",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
            ':dt' : "12-11-2019":{
                       "garage" : "Crazycars",
                       "city" : "NY",
                       "country" "USA",
                       "location" : "120 E Suffolk Ave Central Islip"
               }
        }
                },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#d1' : 'MaintenanceList'
                },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

but overwrite the attribute MaintenanceList and I need it to look like this after update:

```
{
"OwnerID":"12312wqeq", 
"license":"23423werwegdf",
"MaintenanceList":{
        "10-11-2018":{
                      "garage" : "lopcars",
                      "city" : "NY",
                      "country" "USA",
                      "location" : "1929-1927 Fulton St Brooklyn"
              },
        "12-11-2019":{
                       "garage" : "Crazycars",
                       "city" : "NY",
                       "country" "USA",
                       "location" : "120 E Suffolk Ave Central Islip"
               }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SET MaintenanceList=:dt` expression indeed replaces the value of the the attributed called MaintenanceList. If you wanted the content of this attribute to be a hash table, and add to it, you need to update it using a **nested atribute** path as explained [in this DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingNestedMapAttributes). For example do something like `SET #d1.#date=:dt`.

However, note that keeping a hash table inside a single attribute's value is problematic - its total size is strictly limited (to 400KB) and you'll also pay for the entire item size every time you read or write a small part of it.